# Split a string in a cell on a pipe then proper capatlization then join on a pipe

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have 100 or so rows in column A that are pipe-delimited

example
`climate change adaptation|Sustainable landscapes|Biodiversity|agriculture`

I want to split on the pipe then make all the separate words have the first letter capitalized then join then to a pipe so I end up with
`Climate Change Adaptation|Sustainable Landscapes|Biodiversity|Agriculture`

I have
`=TEXTJOIN("|", false,PROPER(SPLIT(A4, "|")))`

but this only gives me `Climate Change Adaptation` I am missing the rest of the string

Thanks

Comment: I got it  `=Join("|",SPLIT(PROPER(A4), "|"))`

Comment: do you really need split and join? Just `=PROPER(A1)` ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ADzqyjG.png))

Comment: sigh, I did not even try that as there was nothing in it description that said it would work on delimited strings. So this works `=arrayformula(PROPER(A2:A))`